# Laradock in laravel got py error

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows, laradock

I use laradock to up my laravel but I got an error if I use `docker-compose ps` this is the error

[image: error]

But I dont have/use a **python file** in my laravel

EDIT

**docker-compose version**

```
docker-compose version 1.21.1, build 7641a569
docker-py version: 3.2.1
CPython version: 3.6.4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k 26 Jan 2017
```

Im using **Docker for windows**

Answer (score 0):

It seems an error of docker compose itself. 
Try to reinstall it

Comment: so do you mean Im gonna reinstall the docker? Is it ok just to reset it?

Comment: For me it looks like an error caused by the py file from docker compose. So I don't think it's an issue about docker. It's an issue about docker-compose. Try to reinstall docker-compose

Comment: im using docker for windows